# How can configure NordVPN so that it doesn't ask me to login each time I turn on the computer?

Tags: windows, login, nordvpn

NordVPN asks me to login each time I turn on the computer. How can I avoid that? It's especially annoying as it requires to turn off/on the kill switch. I do want Nord VPN at startup, but I don't want to login each time.

[image]

I use Windows 7. Startup is enabled in nordvpn settings:

[image]

Comment: Did you disable startup in Windows 10 Task Manager / Startup tab?

Comment: @John I use windows 7, startup is enabled in nordvpn settings

Comment: Get SysInternal / Autoruns and use Autoruns to disable Nord VPN startup.

Comment: @John Oh I see. I do want Nord VPN at startup, but I don't want to login each time.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure about stopping login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I talked to Nord about that when they moved to web-based login. Not my cup of tea. But it is what it is, and won't be changing. Especially annoying as I've not had to login with the MacOS client since 2019, if not longer... The Linux client can at times be a bit cranky. I've never had to touch the kill switch, tho - are you sure it's actually off in the settings?

One possibility is using [OpenVPN Connect-](https://openvpn.net/vpn-client/) or [Community client](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/) instead of Nord's. The configuration files are [here](https://nordvpn.com/ovpn/) and instructions [here](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Windows/1047409832/How-to-set-up-manual-connection-on-Windows-7-and-above.htm). Both work, Connect is maybe a bit simpler.

Pluspoint are that OVPN clients are quite a lot quicker than Nord's own, and you can save your login credentials i.e. autologin on connect. Minuspoints are that you lose all Nord-specific options like Quick Connect, Kill Switch, all speciality servers (unless you find correct config files), NordLynx protocol...

OpenVPN Community client can be run from command line, and is scriptable. I've actually not tested it, but if it can also save the login details, it can be scripted to login and open the connection automagically when you login to Windows, or even before.

If you want to stick with their client and figure out the Kill Switch problem, go to [Nordvpn.com](https://nordvpn.com/) and have a chat. You get first a bot, but just type `live agent` and it'll connect you to one. I've talked with them several times - not for problems but options and alternatives, last time about alternative clients. My experience has always been good, without exceptions. Nord's support documentation is also very good.

Comment: Thanks, great info! From my understanding, to be able to login with the NordVPN client one has to turn off the kill switch (otherwise the browser won't  have access to Internet).

Comment: LOL added a bit :-) Yes, of course. But it's not automatically on unless you configure it in the preferences. in which case there's no problem. I can't remember if my login screen shows that message, but I am certain that I've never turned it on, so if it's there i've never touched that checkbox either. But then again - your client version might be newer than mine, maybe it's another helpful option. The support guys know.